# Entity framework not creating .cs file for new table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-first

I'm using Entity framework 5 with a database first approach. I created a new database table and updated my .edmx. The .cs file was not created for my Model.tt, as explained [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/453) this is a bug in VS 2012.

I followed the work arounds as explained [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734333/entity-framework-5-update-model-from-database-does-not-generate-table-class) and I eventually updated to VS2012.4. The .cs file is still not created for my new table, any idea why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to delete my edmx file and create a new connection to the database, and this error:

> Connection failed, your password expired

Needless to say, a lot of time could have been saved if entity framework at least warned me when updating my model from database that my password expired, instead of just 'Updating' as if nothing is wrong.

So I renewed my password and guess what, everything is working!

Answer (score 3):

Your Tables must have primary key to create .cs files.

Comment: The table have a primary key, it's not creating.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a source control system that could be setting the directory as read only ? I've seen that problem before where automated tools were not generating what they are supposed to be doing because of that.

If you are using source control, check out the whole directory, exit VS. Open it back again and try to generate again.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This was not my problem, my SQL password expired, would have been nice if entity framework warned me instead of continuing like nothings wrong.

Comment: Yes, it also did not warn me of a read only directory either. EF is mute apparently :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem both with and without an .edmx file and both times the problem was the same. When you create and save a new table in SQL Server, EF can't see it until you click on Tables > Refresh in the Object Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that my .context.tt file and my .tt file had the wrong .edmx file name in them for the inputFile string variable. I believe this occurred as a result of someone renaming the .edmx file at some point.